# Passing Dropdown value to api using React

Tags: reactjs

```
<select selected={this.state.Dropdownvalue} onChange={this.handleint} >
  <option disabled>select</option>
  <option value="CashWithdraw" onClick={this.dropdownclick}>Withdraw</option>
  <option value="Deposit" onClick={this.dropdownclick}>Deposit</option>
</select>
```

I am not able to pass the select value to api. The `POST` request is called within `this.dropdownclick`.

```
dropdownclick = () => { 
  const headers = { 
    'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
    'Accept': 'application/json', 
  } 
  debugger 
  Axios.post('--myrequest---', this.state ,{ headers:headers }) 
  .then(res =>{ 
    console.log(res.data) 
    this.setState({ details:res.data }) 
  }) 
  .catch(Error =>{ console.log(Error) }) 
}
```

I am setting the state as `select` and changing the state value with the `handleint` event listener.

**Expected functionality::**

If I click either `Deposit` or `Withdraw`, it should fetch the data. 
  I need a solution thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please share the code for your handler functions?
Also please read : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @UtsavPatel dropdownclick = () =>{
      const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
    }
    debugger
    Axios.post('--myrequest---', this.state ,{
      headers:headers
    })
    .then(res =>{
      console.log(res.data)
      this.setState({
        details:res.data                  
    })
    })
    .catch(Error =>{
      console.log(Error)
    })
    }

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code. Code in the comments is not readable.

Comment: @FabianH. check it now

Comment: @ArvindUdayashankar also share handleint

Comment: @dondragon2     handleint = (event)=>{ 
       let {value} = event.target;
       console.log(value)
      this.setState({ Dropdownvalue:value});   
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need the `onClick` on the options. You can handle the fetch in the `handleChange`. Check the following link below for more information.

https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Comment: I think its based on form..?

Comment: no what you should be doing is the fetch in the handleChange. You don't need a onClick on the options. The link above will help you

Comment: Yeah I totally get it  but is there any way to fetch without that submit button,like once I click the options it must bring the data.

Comment: that is what the handleChange will do

Comment: @ArvindUdayashankar please accept this as the answer if it is working. thanks